# How To Keep textarea content

Tags: php

I have a code :

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['data'])) {
        $myFile = "/var/www/vhosts/domain/subdomain/index.php";
        $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w');
        fwrite($fh, $_POST['data']);
    } else {
        $myFile = "/var/www/vhosts/domain/subdomain/index.php";
        $fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
        $theData = fread($fh, filesize($myFile));
    }
    fclose($fh);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="test" method="post" action="">
            <textarea name="data"><?php echo $theData; ?></textarea>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update File" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I click submit content of the textarea is lost.
How can I solve this?

Comment: is file creating??

Comment: When you submit the form very first time, the `index.php` file will have any content?

Comment: yes i get empty form

Comment: if you add `var_dump($_POST['data'])` as the first step, do you get anything back?

Comment: @AZUMKHOLISHUL, you up voted my answer? Did it work?

Comment: i want to edit index.php with this code but when i clik submit i got blank/empty form

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay it notting work :(

Answer (score 2):

You need to add $theData variable in submit also because after submitting you again need to read the data in order to show them.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['data'])) {
    $myFile = "/var/www/vhosts/domain/subdomain/index.php";

    //here I changed the permission with read/write mode.
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'rw');
    fwrite($fh, $_POST['data']);
    //this line to be added for getting the data after inserting.
    $theData = fread($fh, filesize($myFile));
} else {
    $myFile = "/var/www/vhosts/domain/subdomain/index.php";
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
    $theData = fread($fh, filesize($myFile));
}
fclose($fh);
?>
```

And put htmlspecialchars while echo that variable

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($theData); ?>
```

Comment: And, additionally: the output should get escaped through (htmlspecialchars)[http://php.net/htmlspecialchars] to avoid XSS vulnerabilities

Answer (score 1):

Make a little change in your code:

```
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'rb'); // Notice b here
$theData = fread($fh, filesize($myFile));
```

Comment: What does that flag solve? Its meant to be used for binary files - but you don't want to edit such files through a textarea

Comment: @AZUMKHOLISHUL, you have `fopen` function in your code, just add `b` after r in it. That is what I suggest to do.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to keep the content of the textarea even after the form submission use the code:

```
<?php
$theData = '';
if(isset($_POST['data'])) {

// here is assigning the content to be displayed on form submit
$theData = $_POST['data'];
$myFile = "/var/www/vhosts/domain/subdomain/index.php";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w');
fwrite($fh, $_POST['data']);
} else {
$myFile = "/var/www/vhosts/domain/subdomain/index.php";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
$theData = fread($fh, filesize($myFile));
}
fclose($fh);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form name="test" method="post" action="">
<textarea name="data"><?php echo $theData; ?></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update File" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Other than declaring the variable empty at the start, what has actually changed in this answer?

Comment: @MCMXCII see when there is the form is not submitted the value is read from the table and assigned to the variable and when the form is submitted the content of the textbox is displayed

Comment: @AZUM KHOLISHUL you should accept it, and don't know why getting downvote

Comment: @pravindot17 But it's being set from the post, which doesn't necessary reflect the actual contents of the file. A better approach would be to use the post to update the file and then set the variable to equal the contents of the file, like in Prateik's solution.

Comment: sorry i do not over master php
and my english language is too bad

Comment: Can you please tell us what is the change you did ? I can not notice it.

Comment: @MCMXCII yes you are right, but predeclaring variable doesn't cost anything as if there the same value is going to be written in the file and even if it breaks it will throw the exit

Comment: @pravindot17 But they will only be the same value if the file write works. If for some reason the file write fails but doesn't die, then the form will have incorrect content because it's come from the post not the file.

Comment: i think predefining of variable doesn't make any sense in php right

Comment: actually i didn't get how the code will work and what is the issue he is getting before :-)